# Standard list of odors?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, smell

Is there such a thing as a list of "standard" odors?  In everyday context, there are various descriptions to odors such as "fruity" and "plastic-like".  But are there more accurate and normalized names of odors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a long time since I worked in that field, but there are standard odours, and perfumery has a vocabulary to describe odours.  Common English is fairly weak in that department.  According to [this paper](http://www.fragrancesoftheworld.com/downloads/odor%20maps.pdf) consensus amongst professionals is high, although there are pathological cases (coriander/cilantro).

Answer (score 5):

The problem with odors or taste is that it is a form of [Qualia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia). Whether cyanide smells like bitter almonds or is odorless is subjective. Similarly, whether [Phenylthiocarbamide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenylthiocarbamide) taste extremely bitter or completely tasteless is also subjective (depending on genetics).

Even in everyday life, coffee/wine/spices taste different to different people. Even for fruits, [the Durian fruit can taste and smell fragrant to certain people but utterly disgusting to others.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durian#Flavour_and_odour) This is probably why the perfume industry is making billions - if everyone agree that a certain smell is "nice", everyone would be using the same perfume. [(Do Genes determine our perfume preferences?)](http://www.livescience.com/17626-eau-de-dna-genes-determine-perfume-preference.html)

So I believe it is difficult to have a standard list of odors. Even in the event that the list is created, it will not be universally agreed upon. There are bound to be disputes. Colours on the other hand, (which is also a form of Qualia), are less subjective (everyone can agree that chlorine is green and bromine is brown).

Comment: This argument can be applied to colors as well. How an electromagnetic wave of certain wavelengths is perceived as certain name color is dependent on individual's genetics. But there are still standardized named colors, isn't it? It's a matter of definition and standardization.

Comment: Now that I think about this old question, after reading this recent article about "Turing Tests and the Problem of Artificial Olfaction", https://www.technologyreview.com/s/601220/turing-tests-and-the-problem-of-artificial-olfaction/, I think the fact there has not been a list of standard named odors is mostly because odor is harder to measure, as compared to colors. Traditionally, accurate measurement and quantitative description of odors does not exist (?). Giving names and standardizing the definitions can't happen if there is no measurements.